# SwipeRefreshLayout interfere with GridView inside ViewPager

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, swiperefreshlayout

i have a `ViewPager` for the main layout, with 3 fragment as pages, 2 of them has a `GrideView` inside them.

the main page code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mainRefreshLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
      </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

code of first fragment:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/firstCategoryGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:listSelector="#00000000">
</GridView>
```

the grid view is filled with items. in the middle of list when i scroll upward the `SwipeRefreshLayout` get triggered before the list reach top. *how can i solve this?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hate answering my own question, but i always do:).

so from an example of google [SwipeRefreshMultipleViews](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SwipeRefreshMultipleViews), with a little change in class `MultiSwipeRefreshLayout` i managed to solve the problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/dark_blue"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <com.mehdok.slidingtabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_sliding_tabs"
        android:background="@color/blue"   
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar" />

    <fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
            app:spb_sections_count="4"
        app:spb_color="@color/white"
            app:spb_speed="0.5"
        app:spb_stroke_width="4dp"
            app:spb_stroke_separator_length="4dp"
        app:spb_reversed="false"
            app:spb_mirror_mode="false"
        app:spb_progressiveStart_activated="false"
            app:spb_progressiveStart_speed="1.5"
        app:spb_progressiveStop_speed="3.4"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/downloadBar"/>

    <com.mehdok.views.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_sliding_tabs">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/main_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        </com.mehdok.views.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the java part

```
public class MultiSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private GridView[] mSwipeableChildren;
    private int visibleView = 0;

    public MultiSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mSwipeableChildren = new GridView[3];
    }

    public MultiSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mSwipeableChildren = new GridView[3];
    }


    public void addGridView(GridView v, int i)
    {
        mSwipeableChildren[i] = v;
    }


    /**
     * This method controls when the swipe-to-refresh gesture is triggered. By returning false here
     * we are signifying that the view is in a state where a refresh gesture can start.
     *
     * <p>As {@link android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout} only supports one direct child by
     * default, we need to manually iterate through our swipeable children to see if any are in a
     * state to trigger the gesture. If so we return false to start the gesture.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (mSwipeableChildren != null && mSwipeableChildren.length > 0) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                        if((i == visibleView) && mSwipeableChildren[i] != null && !canViewScrollUp(mSwipeableChildren[i]))
                        {
                                return false;
                        }
                }               
        }

        return true;
    }



    /**
     * Utility method to check whether a {@link View} can scroll up from it's current position.
     * Handles platform version differences, providing backwards compatible functionality where
     * needed.
     */
    private static boolean canViewScrollUp(GridView view)
    {
        return view.getChildCount() > 0 &&
                (view.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0
                        || view.getChildAt(0).getTop() < view.getPaddingTop());
    }

    public void setVisibleView(int i)
    {
        visibleView = i;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell, How you resolved this issue with that MultiSwipeRefreshLayout  class, I am stuck with this issue , couldn't resolve it.

Comment: @Lakshmanan it's been a year ago and actually i don't remember what i have done, but i added my code to the answer. may be you can extraxt something out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Moreover i tried your code, But now, SwipeRefreshLayout  not triggering even the Grid view reached top, Let me try something else, Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: inside `MultiSwipeRefreshLayout` i have a method `addGridView` . you must call it to add view to refresh mechanism. i have 3 GridView so in  `MultiSwipeRefreshLayout` i created an array of 3. modify it as you need and call `addGridView`.

Comment: Yes, I am calling the addGridView, I also have the 3 GridView on the ViewPager, Problem is, Scroll is working fine, But at last after the GridView went top, When I swipe down , The SwipeRefreshLayout not Trigger.

Comment: sorry, the code is a mess, how stupid was i:). you must manually call `setVisibleView` . suppose you have 3 gridview in 3 fragment and a SlidingTabLayout (my case), when ever any of 3 fragment become visible you must call `setVisibleView` with right index.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112481/discussion-between-lakshmanan-and-mehdok).

Comment: After calling setVisibleView , I am again getting the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Extend SwipeRefreshLayout using a new class and override its canChildScrollUp(). return true when you want scroll down for gridview. ex

```
@override.
boolean canChildScrollUp()
{
return gridview.getFirstVisibleItemPostion()!=0;
}
```