# Android : SwipeRefreshLayout with gridview not smooth scroll

Tags: android, gridview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using both `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `gridview` in one fragment. It is getting conflict while scroll. Not scrolls smoothly as it i scroll the `gridview` list, it calls `SwipeRefreshLayout` and get refreshed. How to fix it?

Comment: please post your code of xml.

Comment: added for ur ref. thanks

Comment: Please prefer this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885600/swiperefreshlayout-interfere-with-gridview-inside-viewpager